# How do I write a string to a 2D array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multithreading, operating-system, buffer

So I am working on a multi-threading program with 4 threads. For thread1 I am grabbing input from stdin and then putting it into buffer1, thread2 then reads from buffer1, modifies it, then puts it in buffer2 for thread3 to read, and so on....

After I have read from buffer1 (in my thread2 function), I have successfully altered the data, now I want to put it in buffer2, but I am getting the error of "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". Does anyone know why??

My thread 2 function is below and the error is appearing in `buffer2[write2] = updatedStr;`

```
void *line_separator_thread(void *args)
{
    // Consuming from buffer 1 and producing to buffer 2
    int haveStop = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        // Snag the mutext for a read
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

        // Release the mutex and block on the condition
        pthread_cond_wait(&readyBuffer1, &mutex1);

        // Process all unread slots from the buffer1 queue
        while (buffer1[read1][0] != -1) // Look for no sentinal value
        {
            haveStop = haveStopInText(buffer1[read1]);
            if (haveStop)
                break;
            
            // ***If no break, then read from buffer1, and modify \n to be a space?
            // str_replace(orig, replace, with)
            char *updatedStr = str_replace(buffer1[read1], "\n", " ");
            printf("UPDATED STRING: %s\n", updatedStr);
            read1 = (read1 + 1) % 5;

            // ***Put the updated string in buffer 2?
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
            buffer2[write2] = updatedStr; //ERROR IS HERE!!!

            
            // ***Need to change buffer1[read1][0] So that it doesn't keep looping?
        }

        // ***Unlock the mutex here? Or outside of the while loop?
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    }
    return NULL;
```

Buffer variables and read/write variables are below

```
char buffer1[5][1000]; //inputThread + lineSeparatorThread
char buffer2[5][1000];
char buffer3[5][1000];

// Set up variables to let the threads know where is it safe to read from and write to
int write1 = 0;
int read1 = 0;

int write2 = 0;
int read2 = 0;

int write3 = 0;
int read3 = 0;
```

And lastly, below is in my main function where I am creating the 4 threads

```
pthread_create(&outputThread, &attr, output_thread, NULL);
    usleep(100); // Force the program to allow output thread to actually come up and pend on readyBuffer 3 first

    pthread_create(&plusSignThread, &attr, plus_sign_thread, NULL);
    usleep(100); // Force the program to allow plus_sign_thread thread to actually come up first

    pthread_create(&lineSeparatorThread, &attr, line_separator_thread, NULL);
    usleep(100); // Force the program to allow line_separator_thread thread to actually come up first

    pthread_create(&inputThread, &attr, input_thread, NULL);

    pthread_join(inputThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(lineSeparatorThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(plusSignThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(outputThread, NULL);
```

Comment: Strings cannot be directly assigned to arrays except in intialisers. Use `strcpy` instead. If you need further help please reduce the code to a [mre]. None of the threading for example is relelvant to the actual issue and can be removed.

Comment: But how come when I first put the string text into buffer1 with my thread1, this is what I did: fgets(buffer1[write1], 1000, stdin), and it worked fine. Isn't that directly assigning a string to the buffer1 array?

Comment: `=` is an assignment. `fgets` is not an assignment now is it? Internally `fgets` does "the right thing".

Comment: oooh i see. So how would I use this: char *strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2); to get my updated string into the buffer? so argument one in strcpy would be the buffer1 array, and argument 2 would be my updated string?

Comment: @Jorge Jones: `fgets(buffer1[write1], 1000, stdin)` reads characters from stdin into the memory  locations beginning at `&buffer1[write1][0]`.  On the other hand, `buffer2[write2] = updatedStr` is like saying `array1[] = array2[]`.  You can't do that!  LEGAL ALTERNATIVE: `strcpy( buffer2[write2], updatedStr)`